# bing map isn't include in package

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, bing-maps, windows-store-apps

I've created my first windows store application. I'm using in it Bing Maps.

At the moment I'am creating package (like to Windows Store but I'm not publishing it) for tests on second PC. But Bing Maps aren't working on it. I had to delete them from xaml to run my app. It looks like the libs of bing maps aren't included in package.

Or maybe I'm installing it in wrong way ? I'm installing it by clicking with right button on PowerShell script and I'm running it in power shell. After that my app is available on the pc.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.

After I've run certification of my map I saw that it is failing cause C++ API isn't included and is used by Bing Maps. I've added reference to Microsoft Visual C++ and it solved the problem and certification passed